# Save on typing while using UTF8 encoding

Tags: c#, utf-8

Typing in something like `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(...)` and `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(...)` everywhere in your code could be eliminated by a helper `UTF8` type:

```
public class UTF8_Should
{
    [Test]
    public void Convert()
    {
        var text = "Hello World";
        byte[] array = (UTF8)text;
        string copy = (UTF8)array;
        Assert.AreEqual(text, copy);
    }
}
```

Where:

```
struct UTF8
{
    public static implicit operator UTF8(byte[] array) => new UTF8(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(array));
    public static implicit operator string(UTF8 utf8) => utf8.Text;
    public static implicit operator UTF8(string text) => new UTF8(text);
    public static implicit operator byte[](UTF8 utf8) => Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(utf8.Text);
    public UTF8(string text) => Text = text;
    string Text { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't care about `null` references?

---

IMO you create an object in order just to do something, that is more suitable for the concept of extensions:

```
  public static class StringExtensions
  {
    public static byte[] ToUTF8Bytes(this string text)
    {
      return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
    }

    public static string ToUTF8(this byte[] bytes)
    {
      return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
    }
  }



  Assert.AreEqual(text, text.ToUTF8Bytes().ToUTF8());
```

The benefit of the extension methods is that you don't have to remember that you've created the `UTF8` struct somewhere, because it will show up in the intellisence.

Comment: 1) C# 8 supports non nullable references. 2) We will lost a possibility to declare parameters of type UTF8 which makes sense to have in, for example, IoT domain - you might would like to know how the string is about to be serialized.